# Which class file to include in the "Class under Test" in the jnit test case creation?

Tags: junit4

I'm new to the testing environment,i have small confusion in adding the class file,i want to test the restful web services
Which class file to include in the ***Class under Test*** in the junit test case creation?
Whether the dao class or bean class or service class.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter, you could skip it. The class-under-test is for writing a single unit test for a single class, where the wizard creates the test method stubs for the methods of the class for you.

When you want to test a REST service, you don't need that and could skip that part. Just create the test and name the test method according to the use case or scenario you want to test.

Using JUnit4, the test itself is even a plain java class, the only thing that makes it special are `@Test` annotated methods. So you don't even need that entire wizard.

But in case you want to *Unit*Test the service, you select the service class itself (i.e. the Jax-RS service class annotated with `@Path`)